# displaying images from sd card to imageview according to their ids

Tags: java, android, listview, imageview, android-sdcard

I have a contact list (listview) in my app, clicking on names from the list displays the image of that person, the address, and a call button containing the number of that person.

I am having a problem displaying the image according to the item ids. I have a default image in the folder where the images are stored on the sd card, if any item does not have image then that default image should be displayed there.

I have used if-else statement. The problem is, the if part works almost correctly without the else part, except that items which do not have image access the images of other items. But when using the else part, only the default image is displayed for each item.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // accessing files from sd card
    File file = new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/Frag_list/");
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        listFile = file.listFiles();

        if(listFile.length!=0) {
            for (File listOfFile : listFile) {
               String s = listOfFile.getName();
               if (s.equals(position+".jpg")&& !s.endsWith(".png")) { 
                   // showing the desired image:CONFUSION IS HERE
                   pic = listOfFile.getPath();//retrieving file path
               }
               else {
                   pic =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/Frag_list/default.png"; 
                   // Working also for the IF part
               }
            }
        }
    }
    else
        file.mkdir();
```

Comment: you can try using equalsigonrecase

Comment: not working. I am not having any problem with case @Aayushi

Comment: Hello can anyone help me about this? Got stuck with it :(

Comment: you can try using switch case everything seems ok on your code you can try a different scenario

Comment: That didn't work though. 
But I have found my solution. :)